# How to disable loading mask when I am using ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am confused how to disable loading mask when I sent ajax request to the server using updatePanel.

here my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" />
      <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="20000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" >
   <ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Comment: If you've updateprogress control in your page, remove it.

Comment: @Sundeep: I don't use updateprogress

Comment: So which loading mask is seen on the page?

Comment: @Sundeep: in Timer1_Tick method I load some data from database and it's take several seconds. I got mask entire page when proccess it.

Comment: So, you wish to apply mask or remove it ?

Comment: I mean I want to remove it. Here the capture : http://postimg.org/image/geyfljhq9/

Comment: Ok. Check if there is any animationextender/updateprogress/client side script placed on the page or its master page. Without that, it wont appear on the page.

Comment: My problem is in master page, the source code using UpdateProgress. Thanks very much Sundeep :)